# Download files with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-scraping

I'm trying to automatize download of excel files from a public site containing votes from argentinian representatives. For example, from the following page: https://votaciones.hcdn.gob.ar/votacion/4108

I'm using firefox webdriver and Selenium trhrough Python.
When I try to click the button in the image:
[image]

I receive the following message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
> Element  is not clickable at point (229,480) because another
> element  obscures it

If I try to execute the download excel specific script inside page by `driver.execute_script('javascript:exportExcel();')`
nothing happens.

Is there any way to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could have it done. I used routine proposed in [this page](http://allselenium.info/file-downloads-python-selenium-webdriver/). But had to change `options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel")` instruction by `options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")`.

Working example is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/data")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")

with webdriver.Firefox(options=options) as driver:
    
    driver.get('https://votaciones.hcdn.gob.ar/votacion/4108')
    driver.execute_script('javascript:exportExcel();')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to click the download button and after create automation of download dialog using Autoit or some other ui automator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Autoit. Link:  https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <TabConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIGdi.au3>
#include <WinAPIGdiDC.au3>
#include <WinAPIHObj.au3>
#include <WinAPISysWin.au3>
#include <AD.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include "UIAWrappers.au3"
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIFiles.au3>
#include <GuiListBox.au3>
#include <Word.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Excel.au3>


Opt("WinWaitDelay", 150)
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)
Opt("WinDetectHiddenText", 1)
Opt("MouseCoordMode", 2)
Opt("SendKeyDelay", 10)
Opt("GUIResizeMode", 1)
HotKeySet("^!x", "MyExit")

Global  $Web, $hWnd

$Web = "https://votaciones.hcdn.gob.ar/votacion/4108"

ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "--new-window --force-renderer-accessibility " & $Web, "", "")
WinWait("DSE - Voto Electrónico - Google Chrome", "", 8)
$hWnd = WinGetHandle("DSE - Voto Electrónico - Google Chrome")
WinActivate($hWnd)
WinSetState($hWnd, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
Sleep(7000); Give time for the webpage to load (out of country)

Local $oP6=_UIA_getObjectByFindAll($UIA_oDesktop, "Title:=DSE - Voto Electrónico - Google Chrome;controltype:=UIA_PaneControlTypeId;class:=Chrome_WidgetWin_1", $treescope_children)
_UIA_Action($oP6,"setfocus")
Local $oP5=_UIA_getObjectByFindAll($oP6, "Title:=DSE - Voto Electrónico;controltype:=UIA_DocumentControlTypeId;class:=Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND", $treescope_children)
_UIA_Action($oP5,"setfocus")

;~ First find the object in the parent before you can do something
Local $oUIElement=_UIA_getObjectByFindAll("XLSX.mainwindow", "title:=XLSX;ControlType:=UIA_HyperlinkControlTypeId", $treescope_subtree)
Local $oUIElement=_UIA_getObjectByFindAll($oP5, "title:=XLSX;ControlType:=UIA_HyperlinkControlTypeId", $treescope_subtree)
_UIA_Action($oUIElement, "setfocus")
_UIA_Action($oUIElement, "highlight")
_UIA_Action($oUIElement, "activate")
_UIA_Action($oUIElement, "leftclick")

Func MyExit()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>MyExit
```